# Query to get sales from this month and previous month

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

We'd like to get total sales for this month and previous month.  The query is:

```
SELECT sum(CASE
            WHEN date_trunc('month', date_start)= date_trunc('month', now()) THEN sales
            ELSE NULL
        END) AS curr_sales,
    sum(CASE
            WHEN date_trunc('month', date_start)= date_trunc('month', now()- interval '1' MONTH) THEN sales
            ELSE NULL
        END) AS pr_sales
FROM sales
```

But it returned this error:

"Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.  We're running Postgresql 8.0.2.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `date_trunc('month', current_date)` instead of `date_trunc('month', now())` to get current month in redshift.

> now() is not a supported function in redshift but [current_date](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CURRENT_DATE_function.html) will return a date in the current session time zone (UTC by default) in the default format: YYYY-MM-DD.

**UPDATE**

Query w/ Sample Data >>

```
with sales(sales, date_start) as(
  select 1 , current_date union
  select 2 , current_date union
  select 2 , current_date - interval '1' month union
  select 3 , current_date - interval '1' month
)

SELECT sum(CASE
            WHEN date_trunc('month', date_start)= date_trunc('month', current_date) THEN sales
            ELSE NULL
        END) AS curr_sales,
    sum(CASE
            WHEN date_trunc('month', date_start)= date_trunc('month', current_date - interval '1' MONTH) THEN sales
            ELSE NULL
        END) AS pr_sales
FROM sales;
```

And results are coming as expected:

```
curr_sales  pr_sales
3           5
```

Comment: @ Amith Kumar, the query runs but returns nulls even though we do have activities.  Thanks.

Comment: can you try to do select date_trunc('month', date_start), date_trunc('month', current_date), s.sales from sales s and see if you are getting matching values. I dont have access to your data. You will have to play around.

Comment: Was I able to help? Did it resolve your question ?. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?. As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.